# How to get rid of lag caused by lots of enemy instances?

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization

im making a flash shooter game and ive encountered one problem. When there are a lot of monsters on the stage which are visible by player, the game starts to lag. In my opinion, its due to Event.ENTER_FRAME (each enemy instance has it) where z-sorting, enemy movement, updating other stuff like health is done. Since things like theese, cant be done each second or at similar time interval,im using ENTER_FRAME. My question is, how can i have many instances of the enemy in my game and still dont have it lagging. Ive done optimising in all over the code and if im not mistaken,big ammount of enemies is the performance bottleneck here.

Question me if i wasnt clear; to see the game go to http://ernyz.lhosting.info/bandymas.html or if you want to see the code,i will be able to put it here,just ask :)

Comment: You should post some code. There might be some easy optimizations. Also, how many enemies are "many"?

Comment: Well, 10 active enemies per room make this game lag, so i think, that can be counted as many. Active are those, who are in the same room with player, others 'sleep' and do nothing. Heres whole enemy class <http://www.sendspace.com/file/iqztfp>

Comment: `var penis:Number = 0;` ... what?

Comment: Whoops, i make idiotic var names when im in a bad mood to cheer myself up, ignore that :D

Comment: Why couldn't the updates be done each second? You could create a timer and execute your update code when it fires.

Comment: But walking, for example, cant be updated each second, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, unless you're doing something very wrong, flash rendering pipeline is what takes the most time of your application. And since you get more enemies, you get more MovieClips and more complex rendering.

But having one ENTER_FRAME event for each object is indeed a big overhead that can be easily avoided.

A good practice before optimizing your code is to actually run it through a profiler. I don't believe the actual Flash program has it, but Flash Builder surely does. If you post us a screenshot or a log of the game being profiled, we can be of more assistance.

By quickly playing your game, I've seen that all your enemies are a bunch of graphics with a bunch of gradients, therefore costly to render. Have you tried setting the quality to low? Does the lag go away?

Comment: I dont know what a profiler is, but ill look it up as soon as i have some more free time, since im kinda busy these days and if everything is ok, ill post what youve asked :)
Yes, ive just tried to play the game with quality set to low and it ran smoothly. I suppose lowering the quality a bit would be a good thing, thanks!

Comment: A profiler is a tool that times how long each part of your code is taking to run, so it measures what`s taking most amount of computer time. If you lowered the quality and it ran smoothly, than the problem might be graphics related. One idea is to instead of use graphics for your enemies, just transform them all into a bitmap, it should help a lot since you have so many of them and so many gradients (gradients and alpha blending take a lot of computational time).

Comment: To test things out, replace your whole enemy with a bitmap placeholder and see how it performs.

Comment: Well, Ive replaced all graphics with bitmaps and it helped a lot, Im very thankful for your help :)

Answer (score 5):

Having an enter frame events for each instance is most likely the problem. A single event where you loop over all instances and do actions is usually faster.

There shouldn't be much for you to change: Instead of adding the listener to each enemy, add only one listener to the stage and call the enemies' update functions.

```
class Enemy {
    function update(e:Event) { /* ... */ }
}

class Main {
    function onEnterFrame(e:Event) {
        for each (var enemy:Enemy in enemies) {
            enemy.update(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try this out as soon as possible :)

Comment: Well, ive done what you said, but still, game lags. Nevertheless, ill update enemies as youve offered :)